# Get page to refresh when after submitting data to my G-Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am quite new to HTML coding. I am trying to develop a web form to collect data on a Google sheet. The collected data consists of some text and image as well. **My problem is that I can't get the page to refresh back to the web form after submitting data.** Please help me solve this problem.

I am working off the following code, found at https://mysharepointexperiences.wordpress.com/2016/12/02/upload-file-to-google-drive-and-insert-data-into-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/.

**HTML code:**

```
<form id="uploadForm" 

action="THE LINK TO THE PUBLISHED WEBAPP GOES HERE" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">

<center><label>Calling Name :</label></center>
<center><input required type="text" value="" name="name" id="name"> 
</center><br>

<center><label>Brief description of observation :</label></center>
<center><input required type="text" value="" name="contact" id="contact"> 
</center><br>

</form>

<center><label>Upload Image </label></center><br>
<center><input required id="attach" name="attach" type="file"/></center> 
<br>


<center><input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="UploadFile();" /> 
</center>

<script>
function UploadFile() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
    reader.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
    document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
    document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
    }
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
</script>
```

**Google script (Code.gs) :**

```
var emailTo= "**THE EMAIL ADDRESS YOU WISH TO GET NOTIFIED OF A SUBMISSION GOES HERE**"

function doPost(e) {

try {
var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
var filename = e.parameter.filename;
var email = e.parameter.email;
var name = e.parameter.name;
var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,name,email,e);
return ContentService // return json success results
.createTextOutput(
  JSON.stringify({"result":"success","data": JSON.stringify(result) }))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(error) { // if error return this
Logger.log(error);
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
}

// new property service GLOBAL
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
// see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

/**
* select the sheet
*/
function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}

/**
* record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
* e is the data received from the POST
*/

function record_data(e,fileUrl) {
try {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('responses'); // select the responses sheet

var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues() 
[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a 
timestamp
// loop through the header columns
for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid 
Timestamp column

if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "resume") {
row.push(fileUrl); // add data to row
}
else if(headers[i].length > 0) {
row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
}
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
catch(error) {
Logger.log(e);
}
finally {
return;
}

}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email,e) {
try {
var dropbox = "Images";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
folder = folders.next();
} else {
folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
var file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join("-")).createFile(blob);

var fileUrl=file.getUrl();

//Generating Email Body
var html =
'<body>' +
'<h2> New Job Application </h2>' +
'<p>Name : '+e.parameters.name+' </p>'
'<p>Email : '+e.parameters.email+'</p>'
'<p>Contact : '+e.parameters.contact+'</p>' +
'<p>Skill Sets : '+e.parameters.skillsets+'</p>' +
'<p>LinkedIn Url : '+e.parameters.linkedinUrl+'</p>' +
'<p>File Name : '+e.parameters.filename+'</p>' +
'<p><a href='+file.getUrl()+'>Resume Link</a></p><br />' +
'</body>';

record_data(e,fileUrl);

MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "New Observation Recieved","New observation Recieved",{htmlBody:html});
return file.getUrl();
} catch (f) {
return ContentService // return json success results
.createTextOutput(
JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
"data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Consideration

You are not redirecting your user to the form page when the form submission is successful. You are returning a JSON payload instead:

```
function doPost(e) {

try {
    // ...  
    return ContentService // return json success results
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success","data": JSON.stringify(result) }))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

### Solution

You should return an `HtmlOutput` using the Apps Script `HtmlService`:

```js
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('your-form-html');
```

Or if you have the form HTML in a file inside your Apps Script project you can use:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form-html-filename');
```

You might want also to leverage the `HtmlTemplate` Class in order to show the message you are now returning as JSON in the form HTML rendered page. To do so you can use:

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form-html-template-filename');
template.message = "Upload successful" //based on your try catch for example
return template.evaluate(); // The evaluate() method returns an HtmlOutput
```

In order for this last option to run you will have to build the form HTML with a special syntax:

```
<p>
<?= message ?>
</p>
<!-- Having here below the rest of your form HTML -->
<form id="uploadForm" 

action="THE LINK TO THE PUBLISHED WEBAPP GOES HERE" method="POST">
```

### Reference

[HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)

[Apps Script HTML Templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)