# Datasend reload

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

**What I want? **

If fill the form and click "Rögzít" button I want the form will reload.
But its not work

```
            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'SIKERES', 'row': nextRow }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
              location.reload();
          }

          catch (e) {
            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }

          finally {
            lock.releaseLock()
          }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to supply all the relevant code and files.

Comment: Related questions: [How to refresh/revisit the page after clicking submit on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51461264/1330560); [Get page to refresh when after submitting data to my G-Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64259773/1330560)